# Software - Right click context menu not working

Tags: context-menu

The context menus are not showing when I right click on my laptop.  Does anyone know how to enable it please?  I'm running Windows7.  I've tried holding down the right key for some time and I've added a key to the registry to turn the context menu on or off. 
I haven't switched mouse buttons.  If I did that and the right hand one wasn't working I wouldn't be able to switch back again.

Comment: Are you sure your mouse is working properly? I recommend trying with a different, known good one; borrow one from work or a friend if you don't have an extra laying around. Then [edit] your question to include how that went.

Answer (score 1):

As comment mentioned, assume you dont have hardware mouse proble, run `gpedit.msc` and navigate to the following screenshot, config the policy as `Disabled` and click `OK`, reboot to take effect

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I have the home edition of Windows 7 which doesn't have gpedit.msc